# Send notifications to users when a product in db has expired

Tags: android, mongodb, firebase, kotlin, push-notification

I'm using Flask for backend, Kotlin for Frontend and Mongo as DB.
I have an Android app where users can add some food in a list. What I want to do is sending a notification to the user when one of is product has expired or will expire in two days.

Someone has an idea how to do it ? I think it's possible with Fire Base cloud messaging, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: MongoDB Atlas has Twilio integrations...

Comment: Will it works ? because my mongo db is a local database on a server, not a server from Mongo @barrypicker.

Comment: I am not familiar with Twilio integration on a local on-prem install of MongoDB